# How to Mock Angular JS Promise with Catch and Finally for Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I added catch to AngularJS Promise to handle the exception. it works well but existing Jasmine unit test fail because mock need to be changed accordingly.

Please find the code. 
In the existing API call, I added catch and handleerror function.

```
function calAPI(){
GetAPIData(request)
.then(updatedata)
[catch](handleError)    
[finally](dofinaltask();)
}

function handleError(){

//calling again the same API if the first request fails.

GetAPIData(request)
.then(updatedata)
[finally] (dofinaltask();)

}
```

Existing Mock for UNit Test

```
GetAPIData: function(){
return {then: function() {return { finally: function(){ } }; } };
}
```

I added catch on this

```
GetAPIData: function(){
return {then: function() {return { catch: function(){ }, finally: function(){ } }; } };
}
```

But Unit test gives error as given below

```
TypeError: undefined is not constructor (evaluating GetAPIData(request).then(updatedata)[catch](handleError)[finally](dofinaltask();)
```

Please help me to modify either mock or catch in alternative ways

Comment: can you give the spec code?

Comment: Please find the code added

Comment: Used to write tests like that, gave up quite soon. Use $q to mock promises.

Comment: The Unit test was written and application is online. When I do changes on the application, I need to keep unit test run without failure.